# PL2303 USB: Why connect the red wire +5V?

Tags: usb-power

An [instruction video](https://youtu.be/AywJsMLogRY?t=135) at T=2:12shows the red +5V source connected to the rPi.  In what scenario would one want to do this?

I ask because I would expect the rPi to have it own power supply (in excess of 1000 mA) and doubt that the rPi could be powered by the PL2303's +5V wire.

Comment: you posted a broken link to the video

Comment: Maybe you should ask the author of the video? This connection sounds like a stupid idea, but maybe they had their reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly NOT to connect +5 VDC pin, except GND. The reason is each +5 VDC is not exactly 5 V. If you connect =5 VFC pin to a power source and its voltage is +5.25 VDC while your Rpi power source is 5.00 VDC, then there will be a current flow into Rpi and this may cause some damages to the Rpi.

Comment: Thank you for responding: I think that you are saying that you would not connect the RED wire to the rPi?  I believe it is safe to connect all others (GND,DATA).

Comment: TBH, I don't know which color of the wire. All you will need is to connect the GND + the two data (TX/RX) pins and leave the +5 VCD pin open.